# What is the game-time to real-time ratio in Fallout: New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Like many RPGs, Fallout: New Vegas has day/night cycles. Right now, I'm trying to infiltrate the REPCONN labs to find out why there are so many ghouls there, while still making it back to Novac in time to find out who's killing Bhramin.

I need to be in the Bhramin pen at midnight in order to catch the perp and it takes me about four minutes of real time to walk from REPCONN to Novac. I need to know when to leave to make my appointment.

**What is the game-time to real-time ratio in Fallout: New Vegas?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One in-game-hour transpires in two real time minutes. This can be adjusted by changing the **Timescale** variable using the console, but I would not recommend it.

Keep in mind that, for objectives like the ones you describe, if you miss them, you can always wait 22 hours (or whatever) and try again. Just be mindful of your Hunger/Thirst/Exhaustion meters if you're playing on Hardcore.

Comment: Ordinarily yes, but the rancher is down to his last Brahmin, so it's tonight or never.

Comment: I hate to be *that guy* who tells you that there's no Santa, but... the Brahmin will be there tomorrow night. And the night after. And the night after that and the night after that and the night after that.

Comment: [Waiting and killing the nightkin after all the brahmin are dead will decrease the reward to 50 caps and nothing else.](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Screams_of_Brahmin_%28quest%29#Notes)